# One more Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I should do internal redirects (301) for the list of pages.
Firstly when user opens / or /index.php he should be redirected to em.php, places in root folder. When user opens /contents/about_us/index.php he should be redirected to about_us/enterprise.php
Sound simple but I still can't to solve
When I use this

```
Redirect 301 / http://foo2.bar.com/service
Redirect 301 /index.php http://foo2.bar.com/service
```

it works.
But when I try this

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.site.com/em.php
```

I'm getting http://www.site.com/em.phpem.phpem.phpem.phpem.phpem.phpem.phpem.phpem.php  ...

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Redirect` is going into a loop.

Do this instead either in a `.htaccess` file in `DocumentRoot`or in your `virtualhost` section.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /em.php [L,R=301]
```